# How to read the contents of a Post request on Postman?

Tags: testing, automation, postman, web-api-testing

In the systems I am testing, there are cases that the response informs 200 (ok), but the content may indicate an error in the internal validations of the backend service. How can I read the contents of the response with Postman and schedule a successful validation if this service error code comes as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tests tab in Postman to run checks on the body (JSON and XML). There are snippets which show you the syntax. You can adapt them to check for the element of the response body which indicates the error.

Answer (score 0):

Postman has a tab called "Tests" where you can provide you test script for execution. 
If you want to validate your request responded with 200 OK, following is the script

```
pm.test("Status test", function () {
pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

If you want to validate the response contains any specified string,

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () {
pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("string_you_want_to_search");
});
```

In your case am assuming the above script can be used. In case the response body is JSON,

```
pm.test("JSON Body match", function () {
var respBody = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(respBody.<json node>).is.to.equal("Error_name");
});
```

Example JSON response body 
    {
    "id" : 100,
    "status" : "Bad Request"
    }

```
pm.test("JSON Body matches string", function () {
var respBody = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(respBody.status).is.to.equal("Bad Request");
});
```